# How to hide codeigniter footprint area from online checkers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

is this possible to remove `codeigniter` footprint area from online tools like `wappalyzer.com` or `builtwith.com` and make the 
sensitive project technologies undetectable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

First, you need to know how it's being detected. Have a look at Wappalyzer code:
https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json#L1359

CodeIgniter's presence is being detected by its possible cookie names: `exp_last_activity`, `exp_tracker`, `ci_session` or `ci_csrf_token`. Or possible input name `ci_csrf_token` in the HTML, or precense of `CodeIgniter.png` icon.

You can easily remove such implications from your CodeIgniter app by modifying config files or views. And Wappalyzer won't recognize it anymore.

Don't know if BuiltWith has some opensource code to look at, but I'm pretty sure it uses such kinda implications to detect CI apps.