# Hide Codeigniter from WhatCms detection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanted to know if it was possible to prevent detection of the codeigniter framework from a site like whatscms.org ?

Thank you in advance for your answers and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at the "How We Detect Content Management Systems" section of whatcms.org? It details how they do some of their detection, which would give you some clues as to how to hide. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771762/how-to-hide-codeigniter-footprint-area-from-online-checkers) provides some even better clues as well.

Doing a Google search for "hide codeigniter from cms detector" (without quotes) returns a plethora of results about what you may need to change inside Codeigniter itself to hide.

Comment: Thank you for your help.